# Let $X\subset A$ prove that $\{I : I \text{ is an ideal such that } I\subset A\}$ has a minimum with respect to the contention

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $X\subset A$ prove that $\Theta=\{I : I \text{ is an ideal such that} I\subset A\}$ has a minimum with respect to the contention.

**My attempt**

Consider the set:

$$J = \bigcap_{I\in \Theta} I\subset I\quad\forall I\in \Theta$$

Note that the intersection of ideals is an ideal, this implies that $J$ is an ideal.

Moreover, $J \subset A$ because for all $I\in \Theta$, $I \subset A$

In consequence, $\Theta$ has a minimum with respect to the contention.

Is correct this?

Comment: Is $\Theta$ the set of *all* ideals of $A$? If this is the case, then the minimum will just be the zero ideal (which is equal to the intersection of all ideals). If $\Theta$ is just some collection of ideals, then your approach will work **provided that $\Theta$ is closed under intersection**.

Comment: Other than the use of an incorrect translation (_contention_) and the terrible notation for $\subseteq$, you're missing the critical step where you prove that $J$ is smaller than (that is, it is a subset of) every element of $\Theta$. **Edit:** other weird things are a mention to $X$ and the red part in $J = \bigcap_{I\in \Theta} I\color{red}{\subset I\quad\forall I\in \Theta}$.